# Printing boolean values in python

Tags: python

I have a json input

```
{
     "registryNo":2222904913,
     "resgistrySource":"C22",
      "DateTime":"None",
   
         "Payments":[{
                      "Paymentdetail":[
                                     {
                                     "amount":359.95,
                                     "currencyCode":"GBP",
```

Need to generate a boolean output to check if currency code field has the value GBP. If yes, print currency value as 'True' else 'False'

This is what I've written

```
if "currencycode" in datastore(["Payments"][0]["paymentdetail"]) == "GBP":
     print("currencyvalue") = "True" else "FALSE"
```

--This doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Had a missed quote in "payment details". see if that solves the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand your problem
you can try to do that :

```
if "currencycode" in datastore(["Payments"][0]["paymentdetail"][0]):

    if datastore(["Payments"][0]["paymentdetail"][0]["currencycode"]) == "GBP":
        print("currencyvalue = True")
    else:
        print("currencyvalue = false")
```

If you only want to print 'True' or 'False', do that:

```
if "currencycode" in datastore(["Payments"][0]["paymentdetail"][0]):

    print(datastore(["Payments"][0]["paymentdetail"][0]["currencycode"]))
```

For the timestamp you can do that:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(your_valid_timestamp)
print(dt_object)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Additonally i have my date time stamp coming in as 1597190400000000 ..must be the epoch timestamp..how do i convert it to utc and print it

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add the code to convert the timestamp and print it

Answer (score 0):

As the `==` operator itself returns a `True` or `False` value there is no need to again assign the it.

```
currencycalue = datastore['Payments'][0]['Paymentdetail'][0]['currencyCode']=="GBP"
print(currencyvalue)
```